# Fill up kezayis of bread requirement with mezonos?

Tags: food, bread

If you eat a kezayis of bread you bentch.
If you eat a seduah of pas haba bikisnin you also bentch.

If you ate slightly shy of a kezayis of bread and have only mezonos available, can you fill up the kezayis using mezonos or pas haba bikisnin food items?

Comment: Why would you think this works? You have fulfilled neither criteria. Please [edit] to explain.

Answer (score 1):

r' moshe Feinstein in his responsa "iggros moshe" (exact source will be brought very soon! sorry!!) says that one may not, even for a rabbinic obligation, the reason being that the torah (and chazal) require a "ma'aseh achila" which only takes effect on a k'zayis, only once you have a ma'aseh achila of a k'zayis can other foods be used to complete a shiur of k'beitza and the rabbis ruled to recite bircas hamazon. in our case, again, there is nothing to be m'tzaref to, it isn't anything.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, Michoel, and thanks for the answer! When you find the exact source, please [edit] it into your post. Hope to see you around. :)